# Concurrent parsing algorithms

Tags: parsing, concurrency

Are there existing parser algorithms (similar to LALR, SLR and LL) that can parse a single input, not just multiple inputs, in parallel?

Edit: Sorry, I wasn't really looking for research papers, more like, "There are compiler-compilers that generate concurrent parsers" or "This compiler for this language parses it in parallel"- real world examples.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in parallelism applied to the problem of building up basic program representions (ASTs are just the first in a chain), analyzing or modification. I work on tools that use parallelism in building symbol tables, doing flow analysis, and apply transformations. These tools are used in anger. See my bio.

Comment: Man do I feel silly - I have a book called "Parsing Techniques: A Practical Guide, Second Edition" by Grune and Jacobs with a whole chapter on this, but I'm not in my apartment right now.  I'll try to answer your question once I get back.  The answer is "yes," by the way. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef Really interesting question, this! I may sound like a layman here, but how about setting 'checkpoints' on the input in the first go and simply processing these batches from checkpoint to checkpoint at the same time? That would parallely parse the the input right? I mean this is a sureshot easy way to go about it, is what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any well known ones :-}

Much of the reason is the problem is described as parsing a string, presenting to the parser one token a time.  That makes the problem sequential by definition, ugh.

One could imagine presenting the array of tokens to some parser all at once, and then have the parser parse substrings at various points across the array, stitching compatible trees for substrings together.  The stitching process is likely to be complicated, but might be manageable if driven by an L(AL)R [better, a GLR] parser that swallowed nonterminals left-to-right after most of the parse trees for substrings were produced; think of this an an "accumulator".

[Shades, a quick Google search produces a [1990 Japanese paper on doing parallel GLR with what amounts to parallel Prolog](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/C/C90/C90-2053.pdf)]

You now have the problem of producing the array of tokens magically in parallel.  Now you need a parallel lexer :-}

EDIT June 2013: I finally remembered [McKeeman's 1982 paper on parallel LR parsing](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/references/ParallelLR82.pdf).

Comment: Alternatively, I could just lex in serial and produce the whole token stream, and then parse that in parallel :)

Comment: You could do that. You might find that that serial lexing prevents you from getting any useful parallelism from the parsing process, especially since the amount of work invested in building a token can be more than the work the parser expends processing it. Shift-on-token in an LR parser can be as fast as table lookup, a conditional branch and a state push. Hard to beat that doing character processing.  The standard lore is optimize your lexer hard before bothering with the parser.

Comment: My grammar, unfortunately, requires a little more to parse. Bison gives it a pleasant 143 shift/reduce conflicts and a couple of reduce/reduce conflicts. I think I will have to write a custom parsing solution.

Comment: I don't think that properties of your present grammar as determined by your present parsing machinery will get better just because you go parallel somehow, if you could. If your grammar is experimental, I'd get it right before I'd try anything else. If you believe the conflicts aren't signs of a broken language design, and that LALR just isn't strong enough to parse your grammar, Bison has a GLR switch.

Comment: Parallel was more about maintaining reasonable performance than resolving ambiguity, I'm pretty sure that my new algorithm can cope with the ambiguities. I'm actually parsing the content backwards, because the terminators of each rule are much less ambiguous than the openings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a deterministic context free parsing algorithm with O(N) work complexity, O(log N) time complexity, fine-grained parallelism that is proportional to the length of the input string, and equivalent behavior to a LR parser.  I'll be submitting it for peer review shortly.

The main idea is to process each character in the input stream independently, assume that it could match any rule, then piece together neighboring groups of characters until they unambiguously match a single rule.  Once a rule is matched, it is filtered out by the algorithm.  After all rules are matched, tokens are gathered together into a sequence.

There is some complexity involved in handling tokens with wildcards that could partially nest, and a post-processing step is needed to handle these and maintain the worst-case O(log N) complexity.  This step probably is not needed in practice.

Comment: Interesting.  Once published, please post a reference here so I hear about it.  Thanks.